# How to update prop value when its set in Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In Vue component, when set the 'PROPS' immediately, needs to update the collection to include additional property.

Component is:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['dataArray']   //needs to update this value when it sets.
...
})
```

Comment: the question does not seem to be clear to me, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: also https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 1):

You could change it in the parent by emmiting the value from the child component like :

```
   Vue.component('blog-post', {
        props: ['dataArray']   //needs to update this value when it sets.
      ,
     methods:{
     update(val){
        this.$emit('updatedata',val)
     } 
     }
  })
```

and in the parent component use it as follow :

```
    <blog-post @updatedata="updatedataArray"><blog-post>

    ...
      methods:{
         updatedataArray(val){
         //update your data array   
         }
      }
```

Comment: here, I can not do any change in parent component. also, 'dataArray' same object needs to be updated.

Comment: you could not update props inside child component, or you could change that dataArray to data object property in this case you could update it easily

Comment: you could use watch property  to see changes in your props